# xCode - Send SMS In-App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sms

I wanna send a SMS from my App. I use for that following code:

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

    @interface askFriendsViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

-(IBAction)sms:(id)sender;
```

**.m**

```
-(IBAction)sms:(id)sender{

    MFMessageComposeViewController *textComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [textComposer setMessageComposeDelegate:self];

    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        [textComposer setBody:@"Text"];
        [self presentViewController:textComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];


        [textComposer preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"SMS not working.");
    }


}
```

For the third line in the .m file I am getting an error:

> Sending 'askFriendsViewController *const __strong' to parameter of
>   incompatible type 'id'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you want to send an sms or do you want open the sms UI ? Apple doesn't gave the API to send  sms programmatically. Only user can do it. Not by program .

Answer (score 0):

You declared your class to conform to the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol instead of MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate in your header file. Change that to MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate and implements its 
messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult: method.